# Removing unwanted rows from csv file having more than 10 patterns to be matched

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a `CSV` file which has 2 `columns` and i have to `match` values in a single in row in both the column , if it matches the criteria we have to keep the column otherwise `delete` the **entire row**. Below is an example of my csv file :

```
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   tube of cream
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   kit
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   bottle of topical solution
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   tube of ointment
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   tube of ointment
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   jar of ointment
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   bottle of lotion
lidocaine hcl (gel 2%, soln 4%) generic 1   patch
```

here , the besides rows 4th 5th and 6th all the other rows will be deleted . Reason for that is :

1. first row has **oint and patch on the left** but **cream on right** so it will get deleted.

   Similarly 2nd and 3rd rows will be deleted.
2. The 4th 5th and 6th rows will **not be deleted because they have oint** on left and a **similar word ointment on right.**

So how can implement this `programatically` as i have more than 10 similar conditions to match before a row gets deleted .

Please if anyone can help me out. Thnx :)

Comment: Are the columns separated with a tab or are that 3 spaces or what is it? And please make a list of all conditions under which a row should be kept. If you can't properly define that, we can't implement it.

Comment: @ByteCommander : The input to the` program` will be the `CSV` file , a snippet of which i have showed in my question. So . they are two `columns` just as similar as in `MS Excel` . So please if you can help with 1 condition that i have mentioned ,  then i will try to implement the remaining ones . Thnx for helping out . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can come up with this Python script that takes a file name as command-line argument and outputs the entire content, but without all lines which don't have the string `oint` (case-insensitive) in all columns.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys

COLUMN_SEPARATOR = "   "  # character or string used as column separator. Tab = "\t"
SEARCH_STRING = "oint".lower()  # case-insensitive string that needs to be present in all columns

with open (sys.argv[1]) as f:
  rows=[list(map(str.strip, line.split(COLUMN_SEPARATOR))) for line in f.readlines()]
  for r in rows:
    if all([SEARCH_STRING in r[i].lower() for i in range(len(r))]):
      print(COLUMN_SEPARATOR.join(r))
```

Copy the script above and save it as any file, e.g. `csvfilter.py`.
Make it executable using `chmod +x csvfilter.py`.

Then run it with the file to process as single argument.
Example output with your example above (columns separated by 3 spaces) as `source.csv`:

```
$ ./csvfilter.py source.csv
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   tube of ointment
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   tube of ointment
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   jar of ointment
```

The script will not modify the original file, but just print the new version to the standard output. Also, any whitespace characters between the columns other than the string set as `COLUMN_SEPARATOR` will be discarded.

To replace the original file with the modified version, redirect the output back to the original file:

```
$ ./csvfilter.py source.csv > source.csv
```

You can also save the modified version as a file:

```
$ ./csvfilter.py source.csv > modified.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer , but one confusion is why have you used the `COLUMN_SEPARATOR` here ? . I mean it is a file with columns so you would have given`row` as the name of the `array` to represent each column . That's what i am thinking . please let me know where am i missing. Thank you

Comment: Also , the 3 spaces that i have given in the question is only because it isn't possible to display a file with a `table` structure here ,that's why i had to put the spaces.

Comment: A CSV file represents a table. Rows are separated by line breaks and columns are separated by e.g. `,` (comma), `;` (semicolon), `\t` (tabulator) or whatever. I decided to use the variable `COLUMN_SEPARATOR` which you can easily change to allow you to adapt the script to the specific format you're using. And in the example it was `   ` (three spaces), so I set it to that. What's your problem there?

Answer (score 2):

Oops! some years late, sorry. For completeness, I'll add a bash related answer.

If you don't mind to get the hands dirty with [regular expressions](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/), grep can be your friend:

```
$ cat test.csv | grep -Es 'oint.*oint'                                                                     
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   tube of ointment
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   tube of ointment
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   jar of ointment
```

Here were selected only the rows having 'oint' something in the middle and 'oint' again.

You can use the regex 'or' operator `|` and add other condition, for example, to have the word 'gel' followed by x%, being x a number from 1 to 20:

```
$ cat test.csv | grep -Es 'oint.*oint|gel (20|1[0-9]|[1-9])%'
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   tube of ointment
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   tube of ointment
lidocaine (oint, patch) generic 1   jar of ointment
lidocaine hcl (gel 2%, soln 4%) generic 1   patch
```